# I get Invalid URL: URL can't contain control characters when I try to send a request using urllib

Tags: json, urllib

I am trying to get a JSON response from the link used as a parameter to the urllib request. but it gives me an error that it can't

> url : 'https://openapi.naver.com/v1/search//shop.json?query=%EB%AA%B0%EC%8A%A4%ED%82%A8 &start=10&disp=3'

> error code: URL can't contain control characters. '/v1/search//shop.json?query=%EB%AA%B0%EC%8A%A4%ED%82%A8 &start=10&disp=3' (found at least ' ')

I expected the url requested success

Comment: That double-slash in `search//shop` looks problematic. Possibly the unescaped whitespace before `&start`, too.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes it's the space -- note "found at least ' '". And yes **URL cannot contain a space**; you must encode it as `%20` or in the query part (as here) as `+`. Consecutive slashes (i.e. an empty path segment) are _syntactically_ valid in an authority-based scheme (like https), although a particular server might reject a request _using_ such a path.

Comment: @ceejayoz,@dave_thompson
Thank you ! I found url has one space..omg.. thank you so much!